# Force Enable Hardware Acceleration in Firefox

Tags: 14.04, firefox, hardware-acceleration

Currently, in about:support (Firefox 30) the "Graphics" section states the following:

[image]
Now, I know that Firefox has (for whatever reason) [disabled the hardware accelerated features](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=594876) for Linux users. However, as [stated in this site](http://featherweightmusings.blogspot.ca/2013/11/no-more-main-thread-opengl-in-firefox.html), it should be possible to force enable it. So far, I have:

- Set `layers.acceleration.force-enabled` and `layers.offmainthreadcomposition.enabled` to true.
- Set the environment variable `MOZ_USE_OMTC=1`

It doesn't work, and the hardware acceleration remains disabled. Is there another way to force-enable hardware acceleration (performance is horrible on my computer)? Or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: There is this bug report as well: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=924403 . The silly thing I find with the 'force-enabled' option is that it seems to be the same as enabling it under Settings > Advanced > General.

Comment: Xrender is gone on about [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1178224) as well - note hardware acceleration does not always mean the results will be faster even though it sounds cooler.

Comment: @Wilf Well on my Windows machines Firefox with hardware acceleration on performs much faster than with simple software rendering. The thing here is whether or not I can enable it just to try it out (and hope for better performance :D)

Answer (score 27):

I try this as a answer even if the question actually gave the answer to me. I had problems setting up the environment variable - because it actually went away as soon as i closed the console. It worked when I started Firefox on the same console I used the `export` command but nothing else. I tried setting it in bash and zsh. Then I found a solution and now what is described in the question works perfectly for me.

1. Check if Hardware acceleration is actually enabled in Firefox by visiting `about:support` looking for "GPU Accelerated Windows 1/1 OpenGL (OMTC)" under graphics. If this shows 1/1 you can stop right here, you not need this tweak. But if it shows 0/1 you can force it on ...
2. Open `about:config` in Firefox (url bar)
3. Set `layers.acceleration.force-enabled` and `layers.offmainthreadcomposition.enabled` to true
4. <del>Run `sudo bash -c "echo export MOZ_USE_OMTC=1 >> /etc/X11/Xsession.d/90environment"` to set the enviorment variable globally for X</del> (Is no longer needed for up to date Firefox versions)
5. Reboot and check `about:support` for "GPU Accelerated Windows 1/1 ..."

[image]

Comment: This mostly worked for me - Firefox worked faster, but there were graphic glitches and the entire system's graphics crashed upon trying 3D webgl content :(. Using fglrx drivers. Also, note you can test this by running `export MOZ_USE_OMTC=1` before running `firefox`.

Comment: or another way to set MOZ_USE_OMTC=1 variable is to create in your home folder *.pam_environment* file which is dedicated for user environment variables and add MOZ_USE_OMTC=1

Comment: This works though a nicer way to enable `MOZ_USE_OMTC` on Ubuntu is to add `export MOZ_USE_OMTC=1` in your `~/.profile` file.

Comment: "nicer" is **your opinion**. `.profile` is only at a user basis. `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90environment` is system wide.

Comment: I just changed it to where the variable is set every time I start Firefox. I use a bash script that runs `env MOZ_USE_OMTC=1 firefox`.

Comment: One drawback: if you have an old card (Quadro FX 1700/PCIe/SSE2) the effective driver version remains on 3.3.0 NVIDIA 340.93. And the effect is visible but still renderung is too slow :(

Comment: This caused extreme glitches in my case (fglrx driver), even outside of firefox window. After a while whole screen freezes. AMD users be careful.

Comment: I would recomend testing with @trlkly method before modifying system environment variables - also setting the variable for X may not work for new OSs using Wayland or Mir. I think according to linked bugs here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Platform/GFX/OffMainThreadCompositing#Linux) they may enable this by default at a later date.

Comment: @Wilf Current versions of Firefox no longer require MOZ_USE_OMTC to be set at all. Off main thread composition is turned on by default. Setting he about:config preference layers.acceleration.force-enabled to true is now sufficient.

Answer (score -3):

Try setting `gfx.font_rendering.directwrite.enabled` to 'True'. Then right-click that entry, click New > Integer, type `mozilla.widget.render-mode` as the 'Name' and then 'OK'. Type `6` as the Value and click 'OK'.

[Source](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/enable-graphics-hardware-acceleration-27457.html)

Comment: I think this is a solution for Windows not Linux....

Comment: Maybe. Worth a shot anyway though? You can always reverse it :P